# webpacker syntax for imports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

A rails `assets/javascript` directory has the following sub-directories:
channels
packs
src
I have the following in an `application.js` file

```
import("../src/foundation-datepicker")
import("../src/user_dob")
```

But these files are not importing as  `Webpacker can't find` and therefore not create the manifest.

What is the proper syntax to import these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `webpacker.yml` add your `assets/javascript` directory to `additional_paths` so that `webpack` will lookup modules also in that dicrectory

```rb
# config/webpacker.yml
additional_paths: ['app/assets/javascript']

# app/javascript/packs/application.js
import("src/foundation-datepicker")
import("src/user_dob")
```

Comment: This is interesting.  By default it is set to an empty array.  yet rails generates an application with `channels` and `packs` directories.  does this mean channels is not accessed?  And can on just add subdirectories as needed to remove clutter?

Comment: @Jerome `webpacker.yml` also has `source_path: app/javascript` -> so all `javascript` files in that directory is loaded, include `channels` and `packs`